# Mod Rewrite Rule for API rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel

I'm struggling to work out the correct rewrite rule to write requests to api/1.1/method to api/1_0/method

The framework I use will not allow nested controllers with .'s in the folder names as it uses that as a seperator.

I have been toying with a solution and this is where I got to so far:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(api)/([^.]+)\.([^/]+)/(.*)$ /$1/$2_$3/$4 [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Quick question: Why are you using this methodology for routing? Laravel is designed to take care of these things... `routes.php`. The most influential members of the Laravel community recommend that you specify routes [to controllers] in that file.

Comment: For sure. I could maybe get it working like that but basically I would have to define every single end point and cannot lazy load the controller.

Comment: @David - no - you do not understand how Laravel works - you cannot 'define' every single end point. There is only one endpoint: index.php. *Everything* is routed through that.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(api)/([^.]+)\.([^/]+)/(.*)$ /$1/$2_$3/$4 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: `this doesn't work` doesn't help, you need to provide more details. What is the URI you tried? And post your latest .htaccess in your question.

Comment: I'm hitting this URL http://example.com/api/1.0/user/ which needs to map to http://example.com/api/1_0/user/

Comment: This is fully tested rule working fine on my webserver and I didn't see your latest .htaccess in your question.

Comment: No not on laravel it was tested on independent apache installation.